# What do the --save flags do with npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install

I see instructions to install a package with either

```
npm install <package_name>
```

or

```
npm install <package_name> --save
```

or

```
npm install <package_name> --save-dev
```

What is the difference between these options?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

### Updated, 2019:

Since this question was asked there was a change to npm, such that `--save` has become the default option, so you do not need to use `--save` to update the dependencies.

---

### Original Answer:

`npm install <package_name> --save` installs the package and updates the dependencies in your package.json.

`npm install <package_name> --no-save` installs the package but does not update the dependencies as listed in your package.json.

`npm install <package_name> ---save-dev` updates the `devDependencies` in your package.  These are only used for local testing and development.

You can read more at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json.

Comment: This was the top answer for my google search on "npm --save flag". Please consider updating it with the correct information, i.e. that --save is now the default, and --no-save is required in order to not update the list of dependencies in package.json

Comment: I would like to read an article or blurb on the reasoning of why --no-save was the default until recently. More mistakes and inconsistent behavior in favor of what, disk space?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer to reflect that --save is the default. I see a lot of tutorials and stuff out there where they use the flag and since I'm so new to npm I don't remember a time it wasn't the default, I started wondering what that was all about. ;)

Answer (score 65):

npm install takes 3 exclusive, optional flags which save or update the package version in your main package.json:

`-S, --save`: Package will appear in your dependencies.

`-D, --save-dev`: Package will appear in your devDependencies.

`-O, --save-optional`: Package will appear in your optionalDependencies.

When using any of the above options to save dependencies to your package.json, there is an additional, optional flag:

`-E, --save-exact`: Saved dependencies will be configured with an exact version rather than using npm's default semver range operator.
Further, if you have an npm-shrinkwrap.json then it will be updated as well.

`<scope>` is optional. The package will be downloaded from the registry associated with the specified scope. If no registry is associated with the given scope the default registry is assumed. See npm-scope.

Note: if you do not include the @-symbol on your scope name, npm will interpret this as a GitHub repository instead, see below. Scopes names must also be followed by a slash.

Examples:

```
npm install sax --save
npm install githubname/reponame
npm install @myorg/privatepackage
npm install node-tap --save-dev
npm install dtrace-provider --save-optional
npm install readable-stream --save --save-exact
```

Note: If there is a file or folder named `<name>` in the current working directory, then it will try to install that, and only try to fetch the package by name if it is not valid.

(from official docs) https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: While the `--save` option still appears to work, it is no longer required - the packages are now saved to dependencies **by default**. The logic is now inversed - if you **don't** want to save your package, you need to specify `--no-save`

Comment: Thanks, @Coruscate5 answered my question exactly.

Answer (score 52):

The `--save` flag no longer serves a purpose.

Previously, as the other answers noted, the `--save` flag would update the dependencies in the project's `package.json` file, but `npm install` now includes this functionality by default.

At this point if you want to prevent `npm install` from saving dependencies, you have to use the `--no-save` flag.

Thanks to Coruscate5 for mentioning this in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022926/what-do-the-save-flags-do-with-npm-install#comment79204893_36023156).

More info in the [npm-install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html):

> npm install saves any specified packages into dependencies by default. Additionally, you can control where and how they get saved with some additional flags:
>
> -P, --save-prod: Package will appear in your dependencies. This is the default unless -D or -O are present.
>
> -D, --save-dev: Package will appear in your devDependencies.
>
> -O, --save-optional: Package will appear in your optionalDependencies.
>
> --no-save: Prevents saving to dependencies.
>
> When using any of the above options to save dependencies to your package.json, there are two additional, optional flags:
>
> -E, --save-exact: Saved dependencies will be configured with an exact version rather than using npm’s default semver range operator.
>
> -B, --save-bundle: Saved dependencies will also be added to your bundleDependencies list.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer to cover the current situation

Comment: It clarified my long-standing doubt. Thanks