# TypeError: express is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I'm trying to use `jade` and `express` together. But it is giving me `TypeError`.
I made `npm init`, `npm install express -save` and then `node app.js`. But it is giving me same error `"TypeError: express is not a function"`

```
// Module dependencies
var express = require('express')
  , nib = require('nib')
  , mysql = require('mysql')

 var app = express();

var app = module.exports = app.createServer();


app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(express.logger('dev'))
```

And `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "reddit-node-mysql",
  "description": "A demo of how to use Express and MySQL together",
  "author": "Clarence Leung <github@clarle>",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^2.5.11",
    "mysql": "~2.0",
    "nib": "^1.1.2",
    "jade": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

**Solution**
My modules' version outdated so they can't installed well. I updated version of them, now working.

Comment: checked in `package.json` for installed dependencies?

Comment: Hi ı checked now

`{
  "name": "reddit-node-mysql",
  "description": "A demo of how to use Express and MySQL together",
  "author": "Clarence Leung <github@clarle>",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^2.5.11",
    "mysql": "~2.0",
    "nib": "^1.1.2",
    "jade": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {}
}`

Comment: [edit] your post instead of adding info in comments pls

Comment: I tried it locally, I think the problem is with the version of express u are using, change `"express": "^2.5.11"` to `"express": "latest"` and do `npm install`.

Comment: Yes i express is outdated .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using outdated express ,

Remove
`"express": "^2.5.11",` from package json 
and run

`npm install --save express`

Comment: The `save` flag is [not needed anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023013/1705829) with `npm install` because it is the default.